# Wordpress not saving <p> tags for custom taxonomy term description

Tags: custom-taxonomy, editor, wp-autop

I'm using wordpress API to display content. I'm using the classic editor since guttenberg is bugging out elsewhere.

I noticed that if a paragraph does not have inline styles, wordpress does not save the `<p>` tags in the database. So when I call the api, the response is something like this:

```
first paragraph.

second paragraph.
```

There isn't even a `<br>` tag in between, just a newline I believe.

I just need to style paragraphs to be spaced apart, so I would prefer to have the paragraph tags.

Looked into wpautop function, but i just does not seem to save paragraph tags unless I tweak inline styles.

Any suggestions or alternatives?

Comment: WordPress doesn't save the `<p>` tags in the database, but they should be added in API responses. How are you retrieving the content?

Comment: It's an API call. I guess I forgot one detail - this is for a custom taxonomy description. I re-checked and it seems that for pages it does save correctly.